# C# how to use ListView selecteditem

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, selecteditem

I'm very new to C# and WPF. I've started new project to learn how to use them both together and how to build UI. Bearly started i've stuck on using selecteditem from listview collection. I was trying to display some basic info taken from object selected. On the form I've aded label and some buttons. Main goal was to open second form with detailed info about selected record. But first I wanted to achieve something simple - just to display record ID in label controll. I can get records and fill the listbox with records, but all atempts to read selected data failed (nothing shows in label). Could you please help me and show me how to use selecteditem with label scenario? And hopefully give me some advices on the details window scenario too...
Anyway - all comments regarding my code will be appreciated, plese be patient and remember that this is my first approach to this subject.

For your convenience all the code is available at BitBucket: https://bitbucket.org/is-smok/gama

Thank you for any help.

Part of the MainWindow.xaml file

```
    <Grid>
    <ListView x:Name="lstInventory" Height="180" Margin="5,51,79,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding GetInventory}"  
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedInventory, Mode=TwoWay}" 
              DisplayMemberPath="Inventory_id">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="GamaID" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Inventory_id}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Typ"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Serial_number}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Producent"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Registry_number}" />
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
    <Button Content="Add" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="57,265,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"   Click="AddInventory_Click"/>
    <Button Content="Remove" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="137,265,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"   Click="RemoveInventory_Click"/>
    <Button Content="Edit" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="217,265,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"  Click="EditInventory_Click"/>
    <Label Content="{Binding SelectedInventory.Serial_number}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="120,326,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="24" Width="140"/>
    <Label x:Name="lblInventoryId" Content="{Binding SelectedInventory.Inventory_id}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,326,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="24" Width="105"/>
</Grid>
```

Part of MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DataAccess dataAccess = new DataAccess();
        inventory = dataAccess.GetIventory();
        lstInventory.ItemsSource = inventory;
        lstInventory.DisplayMemberPath = "inventory_id";
    }
```

Part of DataAccess.cs file

```
    private Inventory m_SelectedInventory;
    public Inventory SelectedInventory
    {
        get
        {
            return m_SelectedInventory;
        }
        set
        {
            m_SelectedInventory = value;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should read [Data Binding Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-binding-overview) first. There are a few things wrong or missing here. 1. Assign the dataAccess object to the Window's DataContext: `DataContext = dataAccess;`. 2. Turn the GetInventory method into a property `Inventory` and bind it like `ItemsSource="{Binding Inventory}"` and remove `lstInventory.ItemsSource = inventory`. 3. Make DataAccess implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface and fire the PropertyChanged event from the `SelectedInventory` setter.

Comment: @Clemens Thank you for reply. Inventory GetInventory method and Inventory object are used to fill the ListView. And this is the only part in my project that actually works. But I'll try to follow your suggestions and to make it work. But first going to read suggested docs. TY.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Could you please help me and show me how to use selecteditem with label scenario?

You could bind directly to the `SelectedItem` property of the `ListView`:

```
<Label x:Name="lblInventoryId" Content="{Binding SelectedItem.Inventory_id, ElementName=lstInventory}" ... />
```

But what you should do to be able to bind to your `SelectedInventory` property is to set the `DataContext` of the window to the `DataAccess` object:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    DataContext = new DataAccess();
}
```

Then the bindings should work provided that `GetInventory` that you are binding to in your XAML is a public *property* of the `DataAccess` class:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding GetInventory}"
```

You can't bind to a method. So you should call the `GetIventory()` method in your `DataAccess` class and exopose the results through a property, e.g.:

```
public DataAccess
{
    public DataAccess()
    {
        Inventories = GetIventory();
    }

    public IEnumerable Inventories { get; private set; }

   //...
}
```

**XAML:**

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Inventories}"
```

Also note that `DataAccess` should implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface and raise a notification to the UI every time the `SelectedInventory` property is set. Please refer to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx) for more information about this.

Comment: Hi. Sorry for late reply, I had a hard time at my work and I had to focus on some other projects, so I let this one stay on hold for a while. Now, having some free time I got back to it, and made some changes according to your great suggestions. Everything works as expected. Still working to get expected result, which in my case is to open detailed inventory info in a new app window, but for now all of your suggestions work flawelesly. If you have any additional tips on passing record to new window, I'll be very grateful.

Answer (score 1):

Hi one of many problems is that the Label gets the value only at initialization. The `SelectedInventory` is updated correctly but the Label does not recognize it. To achieve this read about the `INotifyPropertyChanged` Interface, for more information [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Implementation of the Interface:

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
public Inventory SelectedInventory
{
    get
    {
        return m_SelectedInventory;
    }
    set
    {
        m_SelectedInventory = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedInventory));
    }
}

private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

Comment: could, but according to his question this should solve the problem

Comment: No, read my comment on the question. A good answer should address all these points. Right now, `{Binding SelectedInventory}` isn't working at all.

Comment: This answer was very helpful. Using both answers and comments from this threat I've managed to fix my code. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

ListView's ItemsSource has to be binded to **property** of type IEnumerable or derived, binding to method is not supported in wpf.

Comment: Someone cursed me cause everytime I post an answer I get -1 instantly. Hehe